# "cannot resolve symbol Paper" in android studio. Paperdb not working what should I do?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

This code produces 2 errors cannot resolve symbol paper

```
package com.closebuy.app;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.closebuy.app.models.User;
import com.closebuy.app.utils.Common;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TaxiB extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference user_information;
    private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 7117;
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Paper.init(this);

        //Init firebase
        user_information = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.USER_INFORMATION);

        //Init provider
        providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
        );

        //Request permission location
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        showSignInOptions();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        Toast.makeText(TaxiB.this, "You must accept permission to use app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {

                    }
                }).check();
    }

    private void showSignInOptions() {
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),MY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    //Ctrl+O

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            IdpResponse response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                //check if user exists on Database
                user_information.orderByKey()
                        .equalTo(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                if(snapshot.getValue() == null)//if user is not exists
                                {
                                    if(!snapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).exists())//if key uid is not exists
                                    {
                                        Common.loggedUser = new User(firebaseUser.getUid(), firebaseUser.getEmail());
                                        //Add to database
                                        user_information.child(Common.loggedUser.getUid())
                                                .setValue(Common.loggedUser);
                                    }
                                }
                                else//if user is available
                                {
                                    Common.loggedUser = snapshot.child(firebaseUser.getUid()).getValue(User.class);
                                }

                                //Save UID to storage to update location from background
                                Paper.book().write(Common.USER_UID_SAVE_KEY,Common.loggedUser.getUid());
                                updateToken(firebaseUser);
                                setupUI();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupUI() {
        //Navigate Home
        startActivity (new Intent (TaxiB.this, Home2.class));
        finish();
    }
    private void updateToken(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
        DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(Common.TOKENS);

        //Get Token
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String token = task.getResult();
                    //Do what you need to do with your token
                    Log.d(TAG, token);
                }
            }
        });
        /*FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().gtInstanceId()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void OnSuccess (InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {
                        tokens.child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                                .setValue(instanceIdResult.getToken());
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure (@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(TaxiB.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });*/
    }
}
```

I suspect paperdb I'm using is depreciated..

```
import org.gradle.internal.impldep.bsh.commands.dir

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.closebuy.app"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.closebuy.app"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation ("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.6.0")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.runner:runner:1.0.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.places:places:3.3.0")
    implementation("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")

    //Libraries
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.5.0")//implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3")
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2")
    implementation("com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2")
    implementation("com.github.satyajiit:TheSpotsDialog:0.94")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.1.0")
    implementation("com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2")//0.8.5

    //RxJava2
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1")
    implementation("io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7")

    //Retrofit2
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0")

    implementation("io.paperdb:paperdb:2.7.1")
}
```

I originally am aiming at using firebase to gain access to another devices GPS coordinates in real time so I can display the location of a taxi as it comes to pick up the requester. I have already done the current location and destination I just want to now display as a new activity the driver and the client. I need the drivers GPS that's why I'm using firebase. Am I in the right way?

here is the Taxi class where I wasn't using firebase:

```
package com.closebuy.app;



import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;


import com.closebuy.app.adapter.PlaceAutoSuggestAdapter;
import com.closebuy.app.directionhelpers.FetchURL;
import com.closebuy.app.directionhelpers.TaskLoadedCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionDeniedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionGrantedResponse;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.single.PermissionListener;

import java.util.List;


public class Taxi extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskLoadedCallback {

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    TextView textBoda, textBajaj, textTaxi, textMiniVan;
    ImageView imageBoda, imageBajaj, imageTaxi, imageMiniVan;
    ImageButton buttonBoda, buttonBajaj, buttonTaxi, buttonMiniVan;
    Marker marker;
    GoogleMap map;
    MarkerOptions place1, place2;
    Polyline currentPolyline;
    int waycounter = 1;
    LatLng destiny;
    String selected = "None";
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_taxi);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);

        fusedLocationProviderClient = (FusedLocationProviderClient) LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        Dexter.withContext(getApplicationContext()).withPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
                        getCurrentLocation();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                        permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();

        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        adapter = new PlaceAutoSuggestAdapter(Taxi.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                closeKeyboard();
                //textView.setText(adapter.getItem(position));
                LatLng latLng = getLatLngFromAddress(autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString());
                destiny = latLng;

                if(latLng!=null){
                    //textView2.setText("Lat:  "+latLng.latitude);
                    //textView3.setText("Lng:  "+latLng.longitude);

                    place2 = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Destination !");
                    getCurrentLocation();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Taxi.this, "Lat Lng not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        map = googleMap;
                        if(location != null){
                            String url;
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            place1 = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Current Location !");
                            googleMap.addMarker(place1);
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                            
                            if (place2!=null){
                                if (waycounter == 1){
                                    float results[] = new float[10];
                                    Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), destiny.latitude, destiny.longitude, results);
                                    float distance = results[0]/1000;
                                    int umbali =(int)distance;
                                    //textView2.setText("Distance = " + results[0]/1000);
                                    marker = googleMap.addMarker(place2);

                                    url = getUrl(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition(), "driving");
                                    new FetchURL(Taxi.this).execute(url, "driving");

                                    if (umbali>=1 && umbali<=2) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>2 && umbali<=8) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>8 && umbali<=32) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 9));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>32 && umbali<=300) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 7));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>300 && umbali<=1000) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>1000 && umbali<=3000) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 3));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>3000) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 1));
                                    }

                                    String sele = pickRide(umbali);

                                    if (sele == "Boda"){
                                        openActivityBoda();
                                    }
                                    if (sele == "Bajaj"){
                                        openActivityBajaj();
                                    }
                                    if (sele == "Taxi"){
                                        openActivityTaxiB();
                                    }
                                    if (sele == "Mini Van"){
                                        openActivityMiniVan();
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    float results[] = new float[10];
                                    Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), destiny.latitude, destiny.longitude, results);
                                    marker.remove();
                                    float distance = results[0]/1000;
                                    int umbali =(int)distance;//textView2.setText("Distance = " + distance);
                                    marker = googleMap.addMarker(place2);

                                    url = getUrl(place1.getPosition(), place2.getPosition(), "driving");
                                    new FetchURL(Taxi.this).execute(url, "driving");

                                    if (umbali>=1 && umbali<=2) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>2 && umbali<=8) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>8 && umbali<=32) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 9));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>32 && umbali<=300) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 7));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>300 && umbali<=1000) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>1000 && umbali<=3000) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 3));
                                    }
                                    if (umbali>3000) {
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 1));
                                    }

                                    String sele = pickRide(umbali);

                                    if (sele == "Boda"){
                                        openActivityBoda();
                                    }
                                    if (sele == "Bajaj"){
                                        openActivityBajaj();
                                    }
                                    if (sele == "Taxi"){
                                        openActivityTaxiB();
                                    }
                                    if (sele == "Mini Van"){
                                        openActivityMiniVan();
                                    }
                                }
                                waycounter = waycounter+1;
                            }
                            else{
                                //do nothing
                            }

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Taxi.this, "Please on your Location App Permissions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private LatLng getLatLngFromAddress(String address){

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Taxi.this);
        List<Address> addressList;

        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 1);
            if (addressList!=null){
                Address singleaddress=addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(singleaddress.getLatitude(),singleaddress.getLongitude());
                return latLng;
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String getUrl (LatLng origin, LatLng dest, String directionMode){
        //Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;
        //Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;
        //Mode
        String mode = "mode=" + directionMode;
        //Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest +  "&" + mode;
        //Output format
        String output = "json";
        //Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters + "&key=API_KEY";
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskDone (Object... values) {
        if (currentPolyline != null){
            currentPolyline.remove();
        }
        currentPolyline = map.addPolyline((PolylineOptions) values[0]);
    }

    private String pickRide(int dist){

        int bodaRate = 217;
        int bodaFare = bodaRate * dist;
        int bf = Math. round(bodaFare/100)*100;

        int bajajRate = 326;
        int bajajFare = bajajRate * dist;
        int bjf = Math. round(bajajFare/100)*100;

        int taxiRate = 543;
        int taxiFare = taxiRate * dist;
        int tf = Math. round(taxiFare/100)*100;

        int miniVanRate = 652;
        int miniVanFare = miniVanRate * dist;
        int mvf = Math. round(miniVanFare/100)*100;

        if (dist<=4.6){
            bf = 1000;
            bjf = 1500;
            tf = 2500;
            mvf = 3000;
        }
        textBoda = findViewById(R.id.textBoda);
        textBajaj = findViewById(R.id.textBajaj);
        textTaxi = findViewById(R.id.textTaxi);
        textMiniVan = findViewById(R.id.textMiniVan);

        buttonBoda = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonBoda);
        buttonBoda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonBajaj = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonBajaj);
        buttonBajaj.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonTaxi = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonTaxi);
        buttonTaxi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonMiniVan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonMiniVan);
        buttonMiniVan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        imageBoda = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBoda);
        imageBoda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageBajaj = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBajaj);
        imageBajaj.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageTaxi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageTaxi);
        imageTaxi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageMiniVan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageMiniVan);
        imageMiniVan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        textBoda.setText("TZS: "+bf);
        textBoda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textBajaj.setText("TZS: "+bjf);
        textBajaj.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textTaxi.setText("TZS: "+tf);
        textTaxi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textMiniVan.setText("TZS: "+mvf);
        textMiniVan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        buttonBoda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selected = "Boda";
            }
        });
        buttonBajaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selected = "Bajaj";
            }
        });
        buttonTaxi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selected = "Taxi";
            }
        });
        buttonMiniVan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selected = "Mini Van";
            }
        });

        return selected;
    }

    public void closeKeyboard(){
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    public void openActivityBoda(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Boda.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openActivityBajaj(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Bajaj.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openActivityTaxiB(){
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, TaxiB.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openActivityMiniVan(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MiniVan.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

can I get the drivers GPS without using firebase?

Answer (score -1):

the paperdb is found by implementing: implementation("io.github.pilgr:paperdb:2.7.2") instead of implementation("io.paperdb:paperdb:2.7.1")